# How to render a single component multiple times with different data in react keeping each persistent with the data passed previous without rerendering

Tags: reactjs, navigation, navbar

i am new to Reactjs, In my project i am using navBar and on click of various menus in navBar i am rendering same component with different data by passing props. but what i want is , suppose when i go back to the previous menu , i don't want it to re-render with the props that i passed it previously i want it to stay persistent with whatever changes i had made in that menu , right now my changes are gone when i switch to different menu option.

```
 <adminn data = {data[0]} />  -> for NavBar menu option:1 (made some changes with the table on this page)
 <adminn data = {data[1]} />  -> for NavBar menu option:2. (made some changes with the table on this page)

I don't what it to re-render when i switch to different options and what the changes to be saved for each page 

Please help ! Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: What you need is a global statement. You can use redux, where you can store the user actions at client side and can be used when rendering the component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with CSS and have to display only that tab which is currently active. Also you can make your component as PureComponent or you can override shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle method to stop extra re-rendering of your react component.

Memoization enables your code to re-render components only if there’s a change in the props. With this technique, developers can avoid unnecessary renderings and reduce the computational load in applications.

```
const multiply = (x,y) => {
  return x*y
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).